# Using FastAPI Filter "in" with values containing commas

Tags: python, fastapi

I am using FastAPI Filter's in and not_in operators. According to the documentation, arguments are passed in as a comma separated list ([For example,](https://fastapi-filter.netlify.app/#operators) if the filter field is `address_city_in`, you can send `?address__city_in=Nantes,Boston,Chicago`). However, some of my data values are strings containing commas, how can I pass these in? I have tried putting " " around the values, but that does not seem to work.

Comment: Here is the [code in fastapi-filter that does the string splitting](https://github.com/arthurio/fastapi-filter/blob/920cd181e18b05cedcdab248f14e891bfab83b53/fastapi_filter/contrib/sqlalchemy/filter.py#LL75C62-L75C62), it just does a `str_value.split(",")`, so I think it will be difficult.

Comment: Your best bet is probably to encode commas with some other string, and then decode them in your app.